# Can I increase memory and reduce the ec2 instance type?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instance running my test application and the memory provisioned is adequately consumed.
The CPU utilization is not however to its peak and I feel I have over provisioned my instance.

My question is, would it be wise to reduce the ec2 instance to a lower size and just increase the memory?
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3):

The "size" of an EC2 instance includes both the CPU and RAM. You can't decrease the CPU resources of an instance without also decreasing the amount of RAM available.

You may find that you could switch to a different [EC2 instance type family](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/). For example if you are using an M4 or C4 instance type, you might switch to an R4 instance type to better meet your needs.

Comment: I had the same opinion and now it makes sense. Thank you for answering, just wasn't very sure.